# multiple cell selection in extjs 4.2 grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I need to implement a spreadsheet like grid in extjs 4.2 with multiple cell selection feature but I couldn't find any useful source in sencha forum compatible with 4.2! There isn't any selection model for more than one cell in grid, how can I achieve it?

extjs 5 [example](http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/examples/kitchensink/#spreadsheet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a perfect solution, I'd recommend upgrading to ExtJS 5 if possible.

However, there was a [sencha forum post](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?214050-Multicell-selection-mode-on-grid) with similar ability a while ago by creating a custom selection model for cell selection.

Mind you, *I am not the original author* of this bit of code. I was able to get it working in a fiddle.

Here is the **custom selection model**:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.MultiCellSelectionModel', {

            extend: 'Ext.selection.Model',

            alias: 'selection.cellmodel',

            requires: ['Ext.util.KeyNav'],

            enableKeyNav: true,

            preventWrap: false,

            selected: null,

            constructor: function() {

                this.addEvents('deselect', 'select');

                this.callParent(arguments);

            },

            bindComponent: function(view) {

                var me = this;
                me.primaryView = view;
                me.views = me.views || [];
                me.views.push(view);
                //me.bind(view.getStore(), true);

                view.on({
                    cellmousedown: me.onMouseDown,
                    refresh: me.onViewRefresh,
                    scope: me
                });

                if (me.enableKeyNav) {

                    me.initKeyNav(view);

                }

            },

            initKeyNav: function(view) {

                var me = this;

                if (!view.rendered) {

                    view.on('render', Ext.Function.bind(me.initKeyNav, me, [view], 0), me, {
                        single: true
                    });
                    return;

                }

                view.el.set({
                    tabIndex: -1
                });

                me.keyNav = Ext.create('Ext.util.KeyNav', view.el, {
                    up: me.onKeyUp,
                    down: me.onKeyDown,
                    right: me.onKeyRight,
                    left: me.onKeyLeft,
                    tab: me.onKeyTab,
                    scope: me
                });
            },

            getHeaderCt: function() {

                return this.primaryView.headerCt;

            },

            allCellDeselect: function() {

                var me = this,
                    i = 0,
                    len = me.selected.items.length;

                for (; i < len; i++) {

                    me.primaryView.onCellDeselect(me.selected.items[i].position);

                }

                me.fireEvent('deselect', me, this.selected);
                me.selected.items = [];

            },

            onKeyUp: function(e, t) {

                this.move('up', e);

            },

            onKeyDown: function(e, t) {

                this.move('down', e);

            },

            onKeyLeft: function(e, t) {

                this.move('left', e);

            },

            onKeyRight: function(e, t) {

                this.move('right', e);

            },

            move: function(dir, e) {

                var me = this,
                    pos = me.primaryView.walkCells(me.getCurrentPosition(), dir, e, me.preventWrap),
                    cell = me.view.getCellByPosition(pos);

                if (pos) {

                    me.setCurrentPosition(pos);

                }

                cell.position = pos;

                if (e.ctrlKey && me.isSelected(cell)) {

                    if (me.allowDeselect) {

                        var index = this.selected.items.indexOf(cell);
                        this.selected.items.splice(index, 1);
                        me.primaryView.onCellDeselect(me.getCurrentPosition());

                    }

                } else if (e.shiftKey && me.lastSelected) {

                    if (me.getCurrentPosition()) {

                        me.allCellDeselect();

                    }

                    me.selectRange(cell, false);

                } else if (e.ctrlKey) {

                    me.doMultiSelect(cell, true, true);

                } else {

                    if (me.getCurrentPosition()) {

                        me.allCellDeselect();

                    }

                    me.doSingleSelect(cell, true);

                }

                return pos;

            },

            getCurrentPosition: function() {

                return this.position;

            },

            setCurrentPosition: function(pos) {

                var me = this;
                this.position = pos;

            },

            onMouseDown: function(view, cell, cellIndex, record, row, rowIndex, e) {

                var me = this;

                me.setCurrentPosition({
                    row: rowIndex,
                    column: cellIndex
                });

                me.selectWithEvent(record, e);

            },

            isSelected: function(record) {

                record = Ext.isNumber(record) ? this.store.getAt(record) : record;

                if (this.selected.items == null || this.selected.items == '') {

                    return false;

                }

                return this.selected.items.indexOf(record) !== -1;

            },

            selectWithEvent: function(record, e) {

                var me = this;

                var cell = me.view.getCellByPosition(me.getCurrentPosition());
                cell.position = me.getCurrentPosition();

                switch (me.selectionMode) {

                case 'MULTI':

                    if (e.ctrlKey && me.isSelected(cell)) {

                        if (me.allowDeselect) {

                            var index = this.selected.items.indexOf(cell);
                            this.selected.items.splice(index, 1);
                            me.primaryView.onCellDeselect(me.getCurrentPosition());

                        }

                    } else if (e.shiftKey && me.lastSelected) {

                        if (me.getCurrentPosition()) {

                            me.allCellDeselect();

                        }

                        me.selectRange(cell, false);

                    } else if (e.ctrlKey) {

                        me.doMultiSelect(cell, true, true);

                    } else {

                        if (me.getCurrentPosition()) {

                            me.allCellDeselect();

                        }

                        me.doSingleSelect(cell, true);

                    }

                    break;

                case 'SIMPLE':

                    if (me.isSelected(record)) {

                        me.doDeselect(record);

                    } else {

                        me.doSelect(record, true);

                    }

                    break;

                case 'SINGLE':

                    if (me.allowDeselect && me.isSelected(record)) {

                        me.doDeselect(record);

                    } else {

                        me.doSelect(record, false);

                    }

                    break;

                }

            },

            doSingleSelect: function(record, suppressEvent) {

                var me = this,
                    changed = false,
                    selected = me.selected;

                if (me.locked) {

                    return;

                }

                if (me.isSelected(record)) {

                    return;

                }

                function commit() {
                    me.bulkChange = true;
                    if (selected.getCount() > 0 && me.doDeselect(me.lastSelected, suppressEvent) === false) {
                        delete me.bulkChange;
                        return false;
                    }
                    delete me.bulkChange;

                    me.selected.items.push(record);
                    me.lastSelected = record;
                    changed = true;

                }

                me.onSelectChange(record, true, suppressEvent, commit);
                me.primaryView.onCellSelect(record.position);

                if (changed) {
                    if (!suppressEvent) {
                        me.setLastFocused(record);
                    }
                    me.maybeFireSelectionChange(!suppressEvent);
                }


            },

            doMultiSelect: function(records, keepExisting, suppressEvent) {

                var me = this,
                    selected = me.selected,
                    change = false,
                    i = 0,
                    len, record;

                if (me.locked) {
                    return;
                }


                records = !Ext.isArray(records) ? [records] : records;
                len = records.length;
                if (!keepExisting && selected.getCount() > 0) {
                    if (me.doDeselect(me.getSelection(), suppressEvent) === false) {
                        return;
                    }
                }

                function commit() {
                    selected.items.push(record);
                    change = true;
                }

                for (; i < len; i++) {

                    record = records[i];
                    if (keepExisting && me.isSelected(record)) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    me.onSelectChange(record, true, suppressEvent, commit);
                    me.primaryView.onCellSelect(record.position);
                }
                me.setLastFocused(record, suppressEvent);
                me.maybeFireSelectionChange(change && !suppressEvent);

            },

            selectRange: function(record, keepExisting) {

                var me = this,
                    start, end,
                    x, y, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax,
                    records = [];

                if (me.isLocked()) {
                    return;
                }

                start = record.position;
                end = me.lastSelected.position

                if (start.column < end.column) {

                    xmin = start.column;
                    xmax = end.column;

                } else {

                    xmin = end.column;
                    xmax = start.column;

                }

                if (start.row < end.row) {

                    ymin = start.row;
                    ymax = end.row;

                } else {

                    ymin = end.row;
                    ymax = start.row;

                }

                for (x = xmin; x <= xmax; x++) {

                    for (y = ymin; y <= ymax; y++) {

                        var cell = me.view.getCellByPosition({
                            row: y,
                            column: x
                        });
                        cell.position = {
                            row: y,
                            column: x
                        };
                        me.doMultiSelect(cell, keepExisting, true);

                    }

                }


            },

            onSelectChange: function(record, isSelected, suppressEvent, commitFn) {

                var me = this,
                    view = me.view,
                    eventName = isSelected ? 'select' : 'deselect';

                if ((suppressEvent || me.fireEvent('before' + eventName, me, record)) !== false && commitFn() !== false) {

                    if (isSelected) {
                        view.onItemSelect(record);
                    } else {
                        view.onItemDeselect(record);
                    }

                    if (!suppressEvent) {
                        me.fireEvent(eventName, me, record);
                    }
                }
            },

            onKeyTab: function(e, t) {
                var me = this,
                    direction = e.shiftKey ? 'left' : 'right',
                    editingPlugin = me.view.editingPlugin,
                    position = me.move(direction, e);

                if (editingPlugin && position && me.wasEditing) {
                    editingPlugin.startEditByPosition(position);
                }
                delete me.wasEditing;
            },

            onEditorTab: function(editingPlugin, e) {
                var me = this,
                    direction = e.shiftKey ? 'left' : 'right',
                    position = me.move(direction, e);

                if (position) {
                    editingPlugin.startEditByPosition(position);
                    me.wasEditing = true;
                }
            },

            refresh: Ext.emptyFn,

            onViewRefresh: Ext.emptyFn,

            selectByPosition: function(position) {
                this.setCurrentPosition(position);
            }
        });
```

And to use i build a **store and grid** with the following:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields:['first_name','last_name','phone','isOld'],
            data:[{
                first_name: 'Andrew',
                last_name: 'Meeks',
                phone: '9993332332',
                isOld: false
            },{
                first_name: 'Ben',
                last_name: 'Blah',
                phone: '9993332332',
                isOld: false
            },{
                first_name: 'Anna',
                last_name: 'Hohen',
                phone: '9993332332',
                isOld: false
            },{
                first_name: 'Jeff',
                last_name: 'Melborne',
                phone: '9993332332',
                isOld: false
            }]
        });
        console.log(store);
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            height: 300,
            width: 500,
            store: store,
            title: 'My Peeps',
            selModel: Ext.create('MyApp.MultiCellSelectionModel', {
                mode: 'MULTI',
                allowDeselect: true
            }),
            multiSelect: true,
            selType: 'cellmodel',
            columns: [{
                header: 'First Name',
                dataIndex: 'first_name'
            }, {
                header: 'Last Name',
                dataIndex: 'last_name'
            }, {
                header: 'Phone',
                dataIndex: 'phone'
            }, {
                header: 'Old?',
                dataIndex: 'isOld',
                renderer: function(value) {
                    if (value) return 'yes';
                    else return 'no';
                }
            }],
            bbar:[{
                text:'Get Selection',
                handler: function(btn){
                    console.log(btn.up('grid').getSelectionModel().getSelection());
                }
            }]
        });
```

And a [working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/n1a).  I added a `bbar` with a button to grab the current selection which returns the cells selected.